# Multi-column problem with booktabs package

Tags: tables, multicolumn, booktabs

I'm trying to make a simple-looking table with the `booktabs` package.
I would like to make a multi column, followed by another cell. Right now I can't get to make the following cell, where I would like to write "Matas". It's in the first row, I have the trouble

I have tried to make the table set up as I would like it, with the normal table tools in LaTeX, so you guys could see, how I would like it to be.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{bm,mathtools}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{icomma}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Renskincare.com} & Matas \\ 
\hline 
 & Pund & DKK & DKK \\ 
\hline 
Cleansing Gel & 15 & 141,60 & 149,25 \\ 
\hline 
Gel Cream & 21 & 198,24 & 221,25 \\ 
\hline 
Shipping & 10 & 94,4 &  \\ 
\hline 
Valutakurser & 1 & 9,44 &  \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lccr}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Renskincare.com} \\

& Pund    & DKK & DKK \\
\hline
Cleansing Gel 150 mL &  15 & 141,60 & 149,25 \\
Gel Cream 50 mL      &  21 & 198,24 & 221,25 \\ 
Shipping             &  10 &  94,24 &        \\
Valutakurs           &   1 &   9,44 &        \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what is your question? the code runs without error and `Matas` is in the 4th column , after the multicol cell. Also you have loaded `booktabs` but have not used any of its commands (you should not have vertical rules if you do use booktabs)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - The uploaded code contains two tables, the first one is fine, but it isn't very simple. So I have tried to make a more simple look table underneath where I can't figure out where to write "Matas" as in the first table. Thank you for taking time to help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: just put `& Matas` before the first `\\ ` as you have in the first table? or `&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Matas}\\ ` if you want it centred in the otherwise right aligned column

Comment: Thank you everyone! It works with the answer David Carlisle have wrote, but can I move Renskincare.com to just be a multicolumn over column 2 and 3?

Comment: put a `&` before it to make a blank first cell and change the `{3}` to a `{2}` so it just spans 2 cells

Comment: Thank you for your help @DavidCarlisle. I just about the learn the logic about the LaTeX language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for

```
& % blank cell
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Renskincare.com}& % span 2 columns not 3
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Matas}% centre rather than right align the heading
\\
```